# Parsing ssh key with ssh golang package

Tags: go, rsa, ssh-keys, pkcs#8, pkcs#1

I am trying to use the ParseRawPrivateKey() from the ssh package of golang (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseRawPrivateKey). The documentation states that it supports both PKCS1 and PKCS8 types. I have 2 types of keys:

1. PRIVATE KEY (PKCS8)
2. RSA PRIVATE KEY (PKCS1)

But I am getting this following error with PKCS8 type. It works perfectly fine with "RSA PRIVATE KEY" type:

```
ssh: unsupported key type "PRIVATE KEY"
```

Please let me know why this isn't working and help me in parsing both the type of keys. Go version I am using is 1.11.13.

The part of code where I am trying to parse the key file is as follows. err in the following code is where I see the above error:

```
buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(<keyfile>)
key, err := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(buf)
signer, _ := ssh.NewSignerFromKey(key)
```

Following are the key files:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: You should post your Go code and a PKCS#8 test key that is causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Is this because of the go version then? I am using go1.11.13. This playground uses go1.16.5

Comment: Go 1.11 is fairly old and this point, and it is no longer supported. I suggest you try with a newer version. Check out https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/dl@v0.0.0-20210610154546-0cc6883720ee/go1.16.5.

Comment: I can't say for sure. But if the linked code does not run in your environment, that would be a reasonable conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help in the comments above. The issue is go version. This works from go1.12.15+. I followed [this](https://golang.org/doc/manage-install) and got various versions of go on my machine and tried the [sample code](http://play.golang.org/p/MTa5kr9F5We) on various versions.
Following is the difference I saw:

```
bash> go1.12.15 run test.go   
Go version: go1.12.15
&{{144479305181965272490254391937025069107948546376651838223957892566897461066699421944565346422245724715479373672069322891078162435195710365456982744608092875180392440184046997322460990034866647878368774295132982263484396416207829505054992733049356448573060223609095630481896584887339018846095104448737699187657 65537} 2645454723566204235596766259127364434281982020110505605516722936360787849307098377000448841214807965860128605314298601847716479580005988045659387727996573252188486690862166280792012065797946748750551729842440936084694300539272090480528208606882126846797991966205614019665289902037602352045258789517854779073 [13263472511923445942519309104215506888615505598321091479402380111710326104845418963276768049143608185415654643773759208206999416418839087584135630592068539 10893022551378072895182930140189193062535475752041804793170952109393846495498117381783390279015666041475046770751717018290963057312218682415905914066572363] {7952781113394627946919126151017784742893860078911540210485617725403496873766049461844818610237685998048332466877239450168641363925640489886723434697131777 9487036959085061029819053153817214117573277461205763675246221287211528911455232066121921210089814704904294056501922638662306626566165951369990658148707101 11643611777085191570803741719831263049793572409284501604810833118017412892519680723494951942101995443325154130770992562619423947706172758471124284788676524 []}}
&{0xc0000ae0c0 0xc0000ae0c0}

bash> go1.11.13 run test.go
# golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519/internal/field
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210616213533-5ff15b29337e/curve25519/internal/field/fe.go:328:12: undefined: bits.Mul64
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210616213533-5ff15b29337e/curve25519/internal/field/fe_generic.go:17:12: undefined: bits.Mul64
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210616213533-5ff15b29337e/curve25519/internal/field/fe_generic.go:23:12: undefined: bits.Mul64
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210616213533-5ff15b29337e/curve25519/internal/field/fe_generic.go:24:11: undefined: bits.Add64
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210616213533-5ff15b29337e/curve25519/internal/field/fe_generic.go:25:10: undefined: bits.Add64
note: module requires Go 1.17%
```